# Automated ssh login with passphrase?

Tags: ssh, security, password, key-authentication

Logging onto a machine over ssh typically requires a password to be entered before access is granted. Alternatively, a key/certificate (without a passphrase) can be installed onto the remote machine so that logging on no longer requires a password. This is particularly useful for automated or scripted solutions.

However, it is considered inadvisable and unsafe to create a key/certificate without a passphrase. Solutions involving `ssh-add` and `ssh-agent` are proposed as a means to enter a passphrase only once per session, but to still use a key/certificate with a passphrase.

What is the solution for automated connections between machines? How can a machine automatically update from a remote Bazaar repository (via `bzr+ssh`?) on a regular basis, as in a cron job? How can a machine automatically backup data from another machine (via rsync) as part of a cron job? `rsyncd`? This would not be [encrypted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821526/rsync-encryption) though, which is a major disadvantage. I haven't looked at Bazaar daemon/server options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For automated logins you have to use keyless ssh keys as you would have to manually intervene at the startup and provide a pass-phrase and have to resupply it after an restart.

To secure such keys there are multiple solutions - see [man sshd](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%206.0%20squeeze&format=html&locale=en) for more details:

1. Restrict the remote host for the key with the `from=` parameter, e.g:

   ```
   from="*.example.com" ssh_key
   ```

   this will only allow machines from example.com
2. Specify which command will be executed with the `command=` parameter, e.g:

   ```
   command="some command" ssh_key
   ```
3. Use a dedicated user with an restricted shell or only with the necessary permissions, e.g. for backup the user can only run rsync with sudo.

Comment: But where do I put `from=` and `command=`? I mean in which file?